# Print an ArrayList with a for-each loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Given the following exists in a class, how do I write a for-each that prints each item in the list?

```
private ArrayList<String> list;
list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have:

```
for (String object: list) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

Comment: @Xaerxess it's faster that way

Comment: I was just wondering if that was right, but i guess it is.

Answer (score 93):

Your code works. If you don't have any output, you may have "forgotten" to add some values to the list:

```
// add values
list.add("one");
list.add("two");

// your code
for (String object: list) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

Answer (score 36):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class ArrLst{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        List l=new ArrayList();
        l.add(10);
        l.add(11);
        l.add(12);
        l.add(13);
        l.add(14);
        l.forEach((a)->System.out.println(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Code-only answers are often considered not so helpful. Please add some explanation about how this solves OP's question.